# No input file specified when set open_basedir in php

Tags: php, open-basedir

Directory structure of my server

```
/home/server/public_html/maindata
/home/server/public_html/files
```

when I set `open_basedir= "/home/server/public_html/files"` ,out put of www.domain.com/maindata is

```
"No input file specified."
```

how to resolved this isue?

Comment: What is the code? What line is the error on? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: there is no error in code. but browser get output "No input file specified"

Comment: when i  set open_basedir= "/home/server/public_html"  it is perfectly work

Comment: but i want to open_basedir= "/home/server/public_html/files"

Comment: See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) of `open_basedir` for what is it for. `open_basedir= "/home/server/public_html/files` allows your php instance to only access files within `/home/server/public_html/files` and disallow access anithing outside of it.

Comment: It could be that the open_basedir includes everything after the =. So, it is including the " at the beginning and end. Try removing the quotes.